# How should I use sqlalchemy session in bottle app to avoid 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, bottle, pythonanywhere

My bottle/sqlalchemy app is hosted on pythonanywhere.com, not sure if this matters, I hope not. The app throws 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query' after I leave it for a while. Then I refresh it and it works fine.

Please note that I also have the same query implemented without sqlachemy, using only MySQLdb. That implementation works fine all the time, it never throws exception, because it establishes a new connection every time.

I assume, in a hosted env like pythonanywhere, I cannot fiddle with mysql config that may affect this error, e.g max_allowed_packet or timeout.

**How should I create the sqlalchemy engine and the session to solve this problem?**

bottle_app.py:

```
db_host = 'localhost'
db_user = 'root'
db_password = 'gggggg'
db_dbname = 'test'

#web framework imports
from bottle import default_app, route, run, template, redirect

#sqlalchemy and mysql setup
mysql_connect_string = 'mysql+mysqldb://%s:%s@%s/%s?charset=utf8' % (db_user, db_password, db_host, db_dbname)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(mysql_connect_string)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float, SmallInteger
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
DBSession = sessionmaker()
DBSession.bind = engine

#import mysql package for raw SQL
import MySQLdb

#sqlalchemy model class for table 'nevek'
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'nevek'
    # Here we define columns for the table nevek
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    lev = Column(SmallInteger)
    point = Column(Float)
    play = Column(Integer)
    kmp = Column(Float)

#get records from table nevek with sqlalchemy
def get_nevek_from_db():
    session = DBSession()
    result = session.query(Person).all()
    session.close()
    return result

#basic handler will redirect to nevek
@route('/')
def hello_world():
    redirect('/nevek')

@route('/nevek')
def nevek():
    return template('nevek-obj', nevek=get_nevek_from_db())

#get records from table nevek
def get_raw_sql(sql):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user,
        passwd=db_password, db=db_dbname, charset='utf8')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    res = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return res

@route('/nevek-raw')
def nevek_raw():
    return template('nevek-tuple', nevek=get_raw_sql("SELECT * FROM nevek"))


#this will be imported and run by the wsgi.py (in hosted env)
application = default_app()

#this will be used when running on your own machine
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(application)
```

Exception:

```
2015-02-25 12:43:57,107 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-25 12:43:57,108 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 764, in _handle
2015-02-25 12:43:57,108 :    return route.call(**args)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,108 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1575, in wrapper
2015-02-25 12:43:57,108 :    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,108 :  File "/home/bpgergo/bridge/bottle_app.py", line 49, in nevek
2015-02-25 12:43:57,108 :    return template('nevek-obj', nevek=get_nevek_from_db())
2015-02-25 12:43:57,108 :  File "/home/bpgergo/bridge/bottle_app.py", line 38, in get_nevek_from_db
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :    result = session.query(Person).all()
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2241, in all
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :    return list(self)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2353, in __iter__
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2368, in _execute_and_instances
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 662, in execute
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :    params)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 761, in _execute_clauseelement
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :    compiled_sql, distilled_params
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 874, in _execute_context
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :    context)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1024, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :    exc_info
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 196, in raise_from_cause
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 867, in _execute_context
2015-02-25 12:43:57,109 :    context)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,110 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 324, in do_execute
2015-02-25 12:43:57,110 :    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,110 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
2015-02-25 12:43:57,110 :    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
2015-02-25 12:43:57,110 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
2015-02-25 12:43:57,110 :    raise errorclass, errorvalue
2015-02-25 12:43:57,110 :OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') 'SELECT nevek.id AS nevek_id, nevek.name AS nevek_name, nevek.lev AS nevek_lev, nevek.point AS nevek_point, nevek.play AS nevek_play, nevek.kmp AS nevek_kmp \nFROM nevek' ()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please try it and let me know

By using `pool_recycle` I think you can over come it.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#connection-timeouts

replace

`engine = create_engine(mysql_connect_string)`

by

```
engine = create_engine(mysql_connect_string, pool_size=100, pool_recycle=280)
```

Connection Timeouts

> MySQL features an automatic connection close behavior, for connections
>   that have been idle for eight hours or more. To circumvent having this
>   issue, use the pool_recycle option which controls the maximum age of
>   any connection:
>
> engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://...', pool_recycle=3600)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried various pool_recycle and pool_timeout settings e.g.: `create_engine(mysql_connect_string, pool_recycle=3600)`. None of them worked.

Comment: if I recycle connections frequently, that is in every minute, then it fixes the problem. one hour, as you suggested was not enough. this worked: `create_engine(mysql_connect_string, pool_recycle=60)`

Answer (score 3):

PythonAnywhere's MySQL connections time out after about 5 minutes, so you'll need to configure SQLAlchemy to reconnect when that happens.  [This forum thread](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1026/) on the PythonAnywhere site has some examples for Flask, which you may be able to adapt to Bottle, and here are [the relevant docs on the SQLAlchemy site](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic).

Comment: thanks for your response. I have tried various pool_recycle and pool_timeout settings e.g.: `create_engine(mysql_connect_string, pool_recycle=499, pool_timeout=20)`. Unfortunately none of them worked. [Your comment in the forum](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1026/#id_post_7324) indicates that you still get OperationalError, you retry your operation in the exception handler.

Comment: Was everything OK when you used `pool_recycle=60` as per the instructions above?  You might be able to get away with a higher number, perhaps up to 299.

Comment: just to mention that some timeout may be specified in the mysql server side. :)

Comment: I can confirm that setting pool_recycle and even pool_pre_ping have zero effect on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is sufficiently small pool_recycle parameter. There is no need to use session.

```
#web framework imports
from bottle import default_app, route, run, template, redirect

#sqlalchemy engine setup with mysql
mysql_connect_string = 'mysql+mysqldb://%s:%s@%s/%s?charset=utf8' % (db_user, db_password, db_host, db_dbname)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
#pool recicle set to 1 min
#because the pythonanywhere mysql server will close conecctions in a few mins
#see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/engines.html?highlight=pool_recycle
engine = create_engine(mysql_connect_string, pool_recycle=60)

from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, Float, SmallInteger
#sqlalchemy model class for table 'nevek'
meta = MetaData()
nevek_table = Table('nevek', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(250), nullable=False),
    Column('lev', SmallInteger),
    Column('point', Float),
    Column('play', Integer),
    Column('kmp', Float)
)

#get records from table nevek with sqlalchemy
def get_nevek_from_db():
    result = engine.execute(nevek_table.select())
    return result

#basic handler will redirect to nevek
@route('/')
def hello_world():
    redirect('/nevek')

@route('/nevek')
def nevek():
    return template('nevek-obj', nevek=get_nevek_from_db())
```